# fill a database using data of another database in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

i'am working on winform c# and phpmyadmin (database). i have 2 differents databases(db1 and db2).

i want to fetch data of one column of table1 in db1 and
store these information in table2 of db2
such that if there is any modifications in the column of db1, the db2  should be automacally updated.

this is the logic that i used but it's not working:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
namespace GNMS
{
    public partial class doublecoonection : Form
    {
        DataSet ds;
        MySqlDataAdapter da1;
        MySqlDataAdapter da2;
        MySqlConnection connec1; //for 1st database
        MySqlConnection connec2;//for the 2nd one
        public doublecoonection()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str_conn = "server=localhost;username=root;password=****;port=3306";
        string query1 = "select id,city from enugro.city;"; //query1 for 1st DB
        connec1 = new MySqlConnection(str_conn);
        try
        {
            connec1.Open();
            da1 = new MySqlDataAdapter(query1, connec1);// this is how i stored results of first data in object da

            connec1.Close();

            connec2 = new MySqlConnection(str_conn); // open second connection
            connec2.Open();
            string query2 = "insert into enugro_africa.reports(id,city) value(da1);";
            da2 = new MySqlDataAdapter(query2, connec2);//query for 2nd DB
            ds = new DataSet();//store in the temporarily 
            da2.Fill(ds); //fill the dataset "ds"
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;//display the result in a datagridview


        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Please could u help me?.

Comment: Ever heard of [replication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402794/mysql-replication)? If not _please_ do some research before asking such question that is already answered.

Answer (score 0):

you are using Disconnected ADO.Net architecture...That means you do not have to open and close connection...Data Adapter will do it for you. Remove that code and try again

Moreover, your query 2 seems to be incorrect.
you have to call fill of first data adapter which will fill your data set and then iterate through your data set and call second query pass the value which you want to pass.

Alternatively, you can pass whole data as XMl to stored procedure which can do bulk insert